# What event to use with HTML's select tag

Tags: javascript, html

My question is about what event is better to use with the select tag in the case where I want to detect which option of the select is selected in JavaScript.

Until now I've found two way to do it. The first one is to use the "change" eventListener, just like this :

```
selectList.addEventListener("change", function(){
    console.log(selectList.options[selectList.selectedIndex].value);
});
```

But there is two problem with this method. Firstly, this event is not fired at the beginning, so it don't log the very first element, selected by default in the list. Secondly, when clicking on an item of the list, the event is fired two times, which means there is two identical lines in the console.

The second method I've tried is with the "click" event, just like that :

```
selectList.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(selectList.options[selectList.selectedIndex].value);
});
```

The problem here is obviously that the event is fired each time I click on the list, so the log is done at least two times if I want to change the selected item. Furthermore, the default selected item when the list "spawn" is not logged either, which is normal.

So how can I do to log the selected item only once, and make the default selected item logged too ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you want to log the default value exactly? Have you over simplified your code replacing some parts by the console.log?

Comment: "Secondly, when clicking on an item of the list, the event is fired two times, which means there is two identical lines in the console." Can you reproduce this?

Comment: @Vohuman when he uses the click event... One click for opening the select, one click on the option.

Comment: @Salketer That's for `click` events.  OP is referring to the `change` event.

Comment: @Vohuman sorry my bad.

Comment: Yep I simplified my code, lately I will use some properties linked to the value of the selected option but there is no need to put this code over here.
There is a strange thing, I created a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6ehvwwpj/ which is the exact code I'm using, but here the change event is not firing two times, don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change event fires when the `event.target` (in this example, the select element), has lost focus (or blur). So whatever the user does after triggering a change event, will cause the event to actually fire, so you should get only one event per action as it should be. Take a look at this Snippet, the log plainly shows that you needn't be concerned about double event firing.

1. The first click 'wakes up the listener but it's lazy and has one eye open.
2. As long as the select has focus, then the listener is just waiting for unfocus. In order to be unfocus, you must focus on something else by clicking , etc.
3. Now that you are clicking the option, you have officially unfocased from the select thereby causing the change event to fire.

#### SNIPPET

```js
selectList.addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log(selectList.options[selectList.selectedIndex].value);
  event.stopPropagation
});


var ta = document.getElementById('ta');

ta.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  alert('HEY! Why are not focusing on me anymore?');
}, false);

ta.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert('Why are you poking me? that\'s annoying, STOP!');
  }, false);
```

```css
select {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
ol {
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
#ta {
  margin-right: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<select id='selectList'>
  <option value="">---</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>


<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
<ol>
<li>Type something in the textarea.</li>
<li>Click anywhere within this window, except the textarea</li>
  <li>Now reset this Snippet.</li>
  <li>Type something again.</li>
  <li>Now click the textarea.</li>
  </ol>
<button id="btn">CLICK</button>
```

Comment: As I edited my first post, I resolved the double firing by setting the useCapture parameter of the addEventHandler function to false. Does it make sense ?

Comment: No, capture is the 1st event phase, the opposite of bubbling. Read my rambling on about the change event. I know I'm not that eloquent, but I think I get the idea out there...sort of. I believe capture is by default false.

Comment: As english is not my native langage I find it hard to understand. Furthermore I'm lost because I can observe two different behaviour. With my code, the log happens two times, but with the fiddle, only one time. And your snipper only one time also. So I think there is a problem somewhere in my code, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: @Cheitan I added something to my Snippet, I believe will help. About the other code...is it exactly like the one in the question? because that will cause double event fire every time. The first event would be click and the second would be change.

Comment: In my first post I wrote two different methods. Maybe I didn't clearly explained it, but I tried theses two methods separately. So the double-firing is not due to double eventListener, one click and one change. I try change, then click, never both of them ;)

Comment: @Cheitan that's my point, they will fire because your event.target / event.currentTarget is the same node. Basically, it's like this with events: event.target is the event object that represents the node/element/object/jQuery object, etc that's been clicked. event.currentTarget is the object that listens for the event. These two special evento bjects needn't be the same, they can definitely 2 entirely different objects. In your case they are not. So when you click the select, you are also changing it as well. It doesn't matter if there are separate functions. The event chain ...cont

Comment: ...will trigger everything in it's path. The event chain has 3 phases the 1st phase is capturing the event will 'dive' down the DOM on a path called an event chain. It's first destination is the event.target. On it's way down, if there's any other nodes that have triggers or listeners related to the same event type, they will fire as well. This occurs rarely because not many coders add a listener on a button's parent and intentionally set the capture property to true. They logically add the listener on the button and have no clue what a capturing phase is.

Comment: So in my case, how can I avoid the multiple firing ?

Comment: The second phase is At target phase, basically event.target object commonly the button, the text field, the area that's hovered etc. The last phase is bubbling phase when the event chain goes up the DOM . At this point, any elements that have triggers, delegated, listeners, etc. will fire an event if they have the same event in common. This is the phase that everyone experiences. This bubbling phase causes common annoyances like double fire, multiple clicks, bad Feng Shui, a disturbance in the Force, etc.

Comment: At the end of your event handler, use `event.stopPropagation()` that'll stop the event from bubbling. That is if that's the problem. If you have multiple eventListeners that have the same `event.target/event.currentTarget` and/or functions with change and then the same function with click. You should combine them. But yeah if you use  `event.stopPropagation()`  even with a big mess of listeners, delegated and triggers you can prevent double firing 90% of the time.

Comment: I added `event.stopPropagation` to the Snippet.

Comment: Oh, alright ! You have all my thanks for your time and answers !

Comment: You are welcome, sir. But more importantly, did you manage to resolve the problem and/or the reason why you had the issue?

Comment: I do, because for other reasons we had to change our plans, and so the initial architecture has been swept away. The new one is perfectly convenient with what you explained. No more problem ! Here all is working as expected/

Comment: Excellent, I'm happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

`change` event is invoked when `option` of the `select-input` is changed.

> Create a new `change-event` using `Event`constructor and invoke `dispatchEvent` on the target element.

```js
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});

var event = new Event('change');
document.getElementById('mySelect').dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Comment: WTF man ? Can you explain me more what your code is doing ? When I use it the problem of double-firing disappears !

Comment: @Cheitan quiet simple..Create an event and invoke/call it on the target element. Always use change event on select elements..

Comment: Mh, in fact it didn't totally resolved the problem. But I think I've found why. Considering the rest of my application it may be possible that the eventListener is created several times... So I think I'm gonna delete it each time my function is called.

Comment: @Cheitan Which problem is not solved ? Why do you need to invoke change handler initially ? You can get the value later on click of button or something..

Comment: I don't really need to invoke the change handler initially, but I need to fill some fields with values dependings on what value is selected in the list. By default the first value is selected in the list but as the event is not fired, my fields are not filled.
The problem that is not resolved is inherent to my code, not yours, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Select list already have an "onchange" event you can use:

```
selectList.onchange = function()
{
    console.log(selectList.options[selectList.selectedIndex].value);
};
```